# Rails AJAX Destroy - Re-render index issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an issue with a Rails AJAX app which is confusing me, even though it seems very simple! I am dealing with `class Order` in a simple point of sale rails app. The request is being made as the order will be deleted on page refresh (but I am getting no refresh of `@orders`) as I thought I am specifying in `destroy.js.erb`.

#### orders/index.html

```
<div id="orders">
    <%= render 'orders/index' %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'New Order', new_order_path, remote: true %>
<div id="order-form" style="display:none;"></div>
```

#### orders/_index.html

```
<% if @orders.any? %>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
        <%= link_to "Show #{order.id}", order_path(order), class: "something" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete #{order.id}", order_path(order), method: :delete, class: "something" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete order with ajax", order_path(order), remote: true, method: :delete %>
    <% end %> 
<% else %>
    <p>No orders yet</p>
<% end %>
```

#### destroy.js.erb

```
//When deleting order on order index - render orders again.
$('#orders').html("<%= j (render 'orders/index') %>");
```

#### and the relevant actions from `orders_controller.rb`

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

    def index
        @orders = Order.paginate(page: params[:page])
    if params[:search]
      @orders = Order.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @orders = Order.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    if @order.destroy
      flash[:notices] = ["Order was successfully deleted"]
      redirect_to orders_path
    else
      flash[:notices] = ["Order could not be deleted"]
      render order_path(@order)
    end
  end
```

I suspect the issue is in my `orders_controller` destroy or index action, but I am a little unclear on a number of the ways of working with AJAX in Rails.

Link to repo - https://github.com/benhawker/point-of-sale-rails

Answer (score 1):

Might be because after your destroy you're redirecting to the index path

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to be the issue (as far I can tell).

Comment: I think you are - redirect_to orders_path, it's there. right after @order.destroy!

Comment: I must be making some other fundamental error elsewhere I guess. Will keep digging for a solution as keeping it simple and chaning the `destroy` action to `  def destroy // @order = Order.find(params[:id]) // @order.destroy // end` is still not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting no refresh of `@orders`

Your `JS` is likely not firing, you'll need the [following](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to):

```
def destroy
  @order = Order.find params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.destroy 
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Order was successfully deleted" }
    else
      format.js
      format.html { render order_path(@order), notice: "Order could not be deleted" }
    end
  end
end
```

This will fire `app/views/orders/destroy.js.erb`, which seems okay in your OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try Updating  your destroy action to

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
@order.destroy
@orders=Order.all
```

remove all the redirects
will work.